# Why does't Rust match an empty array?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to match on an array in Rust:

```
let s = "x,y,z";
let v: Vec<_> = s.split(',').collect();
let (x, y, z) = match &v[..] {
    [x, y, z] => (x,y,z),
    [] => return Err("empty"),
    _ => return Err("wrong length"),
};
Ok(v)
```

When passing `""` as `s`, I would expect to receive an `Err("empty")`, but I receive `Err("wrong length")` instead. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `"".split(',').collect() == vec![""]`

Comment: Next time you could try `dbg!(&v[..])` or use a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to see what value you're actually getting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`s.split(sep)` will always return at least one element: if the separator `sep` doesn't appear in the input string, it will just yield a single element that is the entire string. More generally, if the separator `sep` appears *N* times in the string `s`, the iterator will always yield *N+1* elements.

So when you call `"".split(',')`, you will get an iterator of a single element `""` because the separator appears 0 times.

Here are two different approaches you can use if you want to avoid this:

```rust
// filter any empty segments, for example:
//   "" => [] instead of [""]
//   "x,y" => ["x", "y"]
//   "x,,y" => ["x", "y"] instead of ["x", "", "y"]
let v: Vec<_> = s.split(',').filter(|item| !item.is_empty()).collect();
```

```rust
// return empty array if input is empty, otherwise return all segments (even if empty):
//   "" => [] instead of [""]
//   "x,y" => ["x", "y"]
//   "x,,y" => ["x", "", "y"]
let v: Vec<_> = if s.is_empty() {
    vec![]
} else {
    s.split(',').collect()
};
```